# Null use in a small Scheme script

Tags: scheme

I'm just learning how to write in Scheme and hitting a road block with the use of Null.  I have the script below from this video series...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qqext1NwmqM&index=2&list=PLgyU3jNA6VjRMB-LXXR9ZWcU3-GCzJPm0

Script...

```
(define (my-map fn lst)
   (if (null? lst)
    null
   (cons (fn (car lst)) (my-map fn (cdr lst)))))
```

This is just redefining the map function in Scheme.  It fails at the third line as "null: undefined. cannot reference undefined identifier" when I pass a function and a list.

I just copied what the video shows so not sure why it's failing.  If I switch out null for '(), that works.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that your Scheme interpreter doesn't have the `null` symbol bound to the `'()` value, as this is not required by the language specification. Either do this:

```
(define null '())
```

Or equivalently this, as you already guessed:

```
(define (my-map fn lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (fn (car lst))
            (my-map fn (cdr lst)))))
```

Notice that the latest [Scheme report](http://scheme-reports.org) states that `(null? obj)` should return `#t`

> if `obj` is the empty list, otherwise returns `#f`

So it's ok to define `null` as `'()`.

Comment: OK thanks!  I guess I didn't expect that to be the case but makes sense